# Is there a file explorer for ubuntu with a windows style interface?

Tags: windows, software-recommendation

I'm fairly new to Linux and just want to be able to see the disk usage and mounted drives in the same way that I can when I open 'My Computer' in Windows. Is there a file explorer for Ubuntu with this kind of interface?

Comment: No, I really don't think there is.